# Get Particular users Network updates in linked in API

Tags: java, api, linkedin-api, linkedin-j

I am using Linked in API.I want to search my connections  by using name. It is done 
What my second thing is I need to get the `searched users new connection` , `get status update   and provide status update`

I am using linkedin-j  jar file.

I get the overall connections new connection.

```
Network network = linkedin.getConnectionsNewConnectionNetwork(linkedinCrawlerWithOAuth.liClientWithAuth);
        System.out.println("Total updates fetched:" + network.getUpdates().getTotal());
        System.out.println("--------NetWork Updates ---------\n");
        for(Update update:network.getUpdates().getUpdateList()){
            Connections newConnection =linkedin.getConnectionsFromUpdateContent(linkedinCrawlerWithOAuth.liClientWithAuth,update.getUpdateContent());
            for(Person person:newConnection.getPersonList()){
                if(!( "private".equals(person.getId()) )){
                    printProfileDetails(linkedin.printProfileById(linkedinCrawlerWithOAuth.liClientWithAuth,person));
                }
            }
        }
```

but i want to get the particular users new connection.Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting network update of type connection (CONN). That would return new contacts made by the profile in context. 
In REST form that would be,

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates?type=CONN&count=50&start=0
```

This is the REST API call. There should be an equivalent signature in the Connections API of linkedin-j jar.